# График, где все оси это функции многих переменных

Tags: python, matplotlib, график, визуализация

Можно ли в питоне нарисовать график с функциями многих переменных по осям? Допустим вместо оси Ox  f(x) = x^2+y^2+z^2, по оси Oy g(x) = x + y + z. Тогда например для точки (1,1,2) будет соответствовать координата (f(1,1,2), g(1,1,2)) = (6, 4).

Comment: Можно нарисовать если знать изначальный набор точек с координатами (x, y, z). Просто проецируем все точки 3D -> 2D по вашим формулам и рисуем на 2D графике то, что получилось

Comment: Да, так уже сделала, но для хорошей картинки нужно сгенерировать много точек и получается довольно таки долго, поэтому искала что-то попроще, но все равно спасибо!